# Scalar derivative of quadratic form where matrix depends on variable

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have the expression

$$K(p(t),q(t)) = p^T  D(q)  p$$

Where D(q) is an n x n symmetric matrix, q and p are vectors (n x 1) depending on scalar variable t.

I need to take the derivative of K with respect to t. What is the correct expression and how is it derived?

Comment: How about the product rule?

Comment: I tried various product/chain rules, couldn't get the expression from my textbook..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write $D^\prime_t$ in matrix form because $D^\prime_q$ is the 3-dimensional object. But you can write the following:
$$
 K(p(t),q(t))^\prime_t=2p(t)^TD(q(t))p(t)^\prime_t + p(t)^T \Big (\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial D(q)}{\partial q_i} q_{i_t}^\prime(t) \Big) p(t)
$$
Does it coincde with your expression? It is a simple chain rule, takin ain account that $q(t)=(q_1(t),q_2(t)...,q_n(t))^T$

Comment: I believe it's the same, yes thanks. Was this expression derived by doing: dK/dt = (dK/dp)*dp/dt + (dK/dq)*(dq/dt) ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Use only notation of partial derivative $\partial$